# How do I give an extension module a different name?

Tags: python, module, python-2.7

I have a package named 'pkg' with several extension modules, written in C++, which reside in shared libraries with names '_module1.so', '_module2.so', etc. These can be imported using the usual syntax:

```
import _module1
```

However, I would prefer that the user see the module names as 'mod1', 'mod2', etc, so that they would do the import like this:

```
import mod1
```

Is there a way to do that without renaming the shared libraries?

Thanx.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind having the original module name in the source code, but just want to use an alternative name, you can use the following syntax:

```
import _module1 as mod1
```

Comment: This is for an API which has already been distributed to users. I don't want them to have to change their code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the import aliasing suggestions, you could create a `mod1` folder in your code, which has an `__init__.py` file that contains:

```
from _module1 import *
```

Now doing `import mod1` will run the `__init__.py` file, which will load everything from `module_1` and put it in `mod1`'s namespace, effectively making `mod1` act like `_module1` (given that the `import *` works as expected).

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen a more complex method used by [`passlib`](http://code.google.com/p/passlib/). Basically, the user-friendly module uses a proxy to handle the dispatching to the multiple submodules that are used in the project, without sacrificing usability.

The main module might look like:

```
from mymodule.registry import _proxy
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = _proxy
```

[`_proxy`](http://code.google.com/p/passlib/source/browse/passlib/registry.py) is basically an implementation of the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), and handles lazy-loading, and such.

If you don't want to bother with a proxy:

```
"""Main module `mod1`"""

import _module1
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = _module1
```